# Bigquery SQL list all orders made in certain country

Tags: mysql, sql

Original data

Main task is to list all orders made in Taiwan, but I also need to convert the date format from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

I tried the below with DATE_FORMAT but returned error.

```
SELECT * FROM `fp-sql-test.Orders.Orders` 
WHERE country_name='Taiwan';
```

**Original dataset**

[image]

**desired answer**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert `Date` type to `DateTime`

```
SELECT col1,..., CONVERT(date_local, DATETIME) AS date_local
FROM `fp-sql-test.Orders.Orders` 
WHERE country_name='Taiwan';
```